# How to position an element to use the remaining space of the screen without overflowing it [TailwindCSS]

Tags: css, styles, tailwind-css

I'm using [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) -a utility class framework- to style my elements. Altough this is more a generic CSS question.

I can't manage to position the box so this gets the remaining space without overflowing it. This is my actual state:

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen mx-8 bg-white rounded p-4 mb-8">
    <!-- SUBTITLE -->
    <div>
        <h2 class="text-lg font-bold text-gray-700 pb-4">Subtitle</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="relative self-auto mb-8">

        <!-- ELEMENTS -->
        <a href="#">
            <img class="absolute z-10" style="top: 131px; left: 235px;"
                 src="{{ asset('some.svg') }}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output (omitting some of the inside elements):

[image: Actual state]

As you can see, the scrollbar shows because the div is too big. In order to see the bothom of the box I have to scrolldown:

[image: End of current state]

**This is my desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

Thanks in advance.

---

### Fiddle

[Link.](https://jsfiddle.net/b3082fc4/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `.h-screen` is 100vh. `.mb-8` has an `margin-bottom:2rem`. So the height is 100vh + 2rem. You can use `[calc][1]` to subtract the margin from the height.

```
.h-screen{
  height:calc(100vh - 2rem)!important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c28145au/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found: w-[calc(100%_-_10px)]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you are using class h-screen which has `height: 100vh;` remove that class from the div.

Comment: The result is the same :/

Comment: do you have a link? or jsfiddle?

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't think of that. I'll add it now (is this btw: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b3082fc4/1/))

Comment: add `overflow: hidden; ` to body tag.

Comment: This doens't solve the problem, just hide the scrollbar.

Comment: you are using h-screen which has `height: 100vh;` remove that class from the div.